# LTC3115 Buck-Boost Converter isn`t able to provide specified current

Tags: current, pcb-design, voltage-regulator, buck-boost

Currently I am designing a regulator circuit based on an [LTC3115-1](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC3115-1.pdf) Buck-Boost regulator which should be able to supply a current of 1.5 A for charging a NiMH battery pack with 18 cells (18...28 V).
As a power source there will be a MeanWell [GST120A](https://meanwell.si/datasheet/GST120A-GST120A-SPEC.PDF) which provides 5A @24V.

Since I am new to the LTC3115 I first built an eval board with the following circuitry to test the LTCs performance. The circuit is a slightly modified application example from the datasheet p. 34.
The frequency is set to 550 kHz and the inductor L1 is 22 µH (Vishay).

[image: LTC3115-1 circuitry]

Now the problem is that I do not get an output current higher than 800...900 mA. Over this limit the output voltage drops to 0 V likely because the LTC stops regulating.
Yes it says 500 mA output but in the load current diagram on the same page of the datasheet it states > 1.5 A for input voltages > 22 V.

As a load I use a Hameg HM8143 in electronic load mode (current sink).

I also tried the following modifications but without success:

- different frequencies (750 kHz, 1 MHz)
- different inductors ([Bourns 22µH](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/54/SRR1280A-1391399.pdf), [CTC 33µH](https://elektronik-lavpris.dk/files/sup2/SMFS1270.pdf))
- electrolytic caps at PVin and PVout ([Panasonic](https://industrial.panasonic.com/cdbs/www-data/pdf/RDE0000/ABA0000C1181.pdf))
- output voltage set to 5 V (Rbot = 240k)
- completely new board
- different setup as on p. 36 in the datasheet

When the output current is increased to high the behavior is as follows:
(yellow: PVout, blue: FB)
[image: Shut Down behavior]

Here you can see the eval circuitry (not necessarily the same config as in the schematic):

[image: PCBA]

I know that it is not easy to find a solution by just interpreting some rough explanations.

It would be super helpful for me to get some ideas of you guys what could possibly be wrong in my setup.

Thanks in advance for any comments, hints or ideas :-)

Comment: R106 and 108 could use a retouch.  What is your input voltage?

Comment: Input Voltage is 24 V.